Troubleshooting OpenLiteSpeed with Django and Daphne: Overcoming 503 Errors
Problem
I recently moved to OpenLiteSpeed Django and have my repository ready to be cloned. I have implemented Daphne to work smoothly with ASGI. However, I am encountering a 503 Service Unavailable error. I am unsure if OpenLiteSpeed can be used without PHP, as it seems to be waiting for PHP to run or is built to work within a PHP environment.
What I Have Tried

Setup:

Cloned my repository and set up everything needed for OpenLiteSpeed.
Created a Daphne service file and configured it to create a socket file for OpenLiteSpeed to communicate with.
Ensured all permissions are set correctly, and verified that the OpenLiteSpeed user "nobody" can access the socket file.


Logs:

Checked all logs (access, error, debug) but found no useful information.
The only consistent issue is the 503 Service Unavailable error.


Configuration:

Removed the Example app block code from the hosts_config.conf file.
Tested the syntax with the -t command, and no errors were found.



Question
Can I use OpenLiteSpeed without PHP for my Django app? If not, what could be the best alternative to OpenLiteSpeed that works with ASGI apps and Daphne.
